# Change dropdown options by accessing dropdown form control in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, frontend

Is there way to set options based on form control name? For select form control

For. e.g if we have countries then typically we assign all countries to countries variable then iterate using *ngFor etc

I want to change options values of countries based on form control name

So, **(selectionChange)="handleSubmit($event)"** I am using on first dropdown

then inside **handleSubmit()** method I want to access specific form control (which will be dropdown only)

and set options (key value pairs) for second dropdown

I couldn't find way to set this up by acccessing/setting up form control like **this.form.controls['comments']**

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
dataYouWantToShow = [
  { example: '1' },
  { example: '2' },
  { example: '3' },
]

secondDDEmpty = [];

hideSubmit(value) {
  value === 'something' ? this.secondDD = dataYouWantToshow : ''; 
}
```

and you use `secondDD` in the second dropdown ngFor. This is very simple example of how it can be done. Depends on the case, but you only need to feed the right data in the second dropdown array.

Comment: Thanks for your response

setValue will set selected value. In my case I have to set whole new option list. so it wont work

Comment: In that case, you need to create an empty array and populate it based on the first selection value. You can hide the second dropdown or show something else like placeholder data if the second drop down depends on the first selection.

Comment: I updated the answer based on your comment.

Comment: Please check my answer for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="boxchain-width-100" floatLabel="always"
    [ngClass]="{'not-allowed': !isFromCreation && config?.readOnly}">
    <mat-label *ngIf="config?.showLabel">{{ config?.fieldDisplayName }}</mat-label>
    <mat-select #selectField [placeholder]="config?.placeholder" [value]="formValues"
      [formControlName]="formControlName" (selectionChange)="handleSubmit($event, config)">
      <mat-option #options *ngFor="let source of sources" [value]="source.value">
        {{ source.displayName }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
```

Above is my code. it is dynamic select form control used for all dropdowns in my application.
So we cannot do explicit assignment for seconf dropdown. If you see its using **sources** for iterarting. **formControlName** all are so dynamic.

In this situation only thing we could do is inside **handleSubmit()** I have second dropdown name by acccessing it need to see how to attach **sources**. How to do that is need to find out.

Comment: I am not quite familiar with material but how do you use this drop down everywhere in your app? Is it a component, directive? Or you just simply copy pasting it? How I would solve this personally is, create a component out of it and use an @Input or in some cases create a directive, depends. But, I've worked very little with material. What you referring to source is basically an array.

Comment: Its a generic component..also json is in generic format. If you see config. those are generic keys

Answer (score 0):

```
  <mat-form-field>
<mat-select #SupId="ngModel" required placeholder="Supervisor In Charge" aria- 
  label="Supervisor In Charge" [(ngModel)]="customerNic">
<mat-option>None</mat-option>
 <ng-container *ngFor="let tempIds of customerList">
    <mat-option value="{{tempIds.CustomerNic}}">{{tempIds.CustomerNic}}</mat-option>
 </ng-container>
</mat-select>
```

Typescript =>
customerList: string[] = ["A", "B", "C"];